# Copy the contents of std::ofstream into an std::string

Tags: c++, file, stl, stdstring, ofstream

I have an `std::ofstream` object that hasn't been flushed yet. Is there a way to get the contents of this `ofstream` and store it into a `std::string`?

What I want essentially is:

```cpp
std::ofstream ofs("somefile.txt");
ofs << "stuff";
someMethod(ofs); //This method streams into ofs as well
ofs <<"blah";
yetAnotherMethod(ofs); //ofs gets violated inside this method as well 
//more data streamed into ofs
std::string s; //Whatever was streamed into ofs should go into s as well for an additional output.
```

Comment: No. How about using a `std::ostringstream` to begin with?

Comment: That makes no sense. You could get the "contents" of an *input* file stream quite easily though (by just reading the file). What is the actual problem you're trying to solve with this? If it's just plain curiosity then that's fine and okay, but please say so. Otherwise please ask about your actual problem directly instead.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Unfortunately there's a piece of code that exists with an implementation that uses ofstream, and I am trying to find a way to work with it. I suppose I will just rewrite it. :-(

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've modified the code a bit more in the hope that the "actual problem" is clear. I am trying to see if I could possibly avoid having to rewrite this code, but it looks like I'm out of luck.

Comment: Modify `someMethod()` and `yetAnotherMethod()` to take a `ostream&` instead of a `ofstream&` parameter. Simple as that and much more universal.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Far too many of those things to fix. I suppose it might just be better that I rewrite the whole thing. If you would please respond with the answer "No", I'll be happy to accept it as I was afraid that was going to be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. "the contents of this `std::ofstream`" is nonsensical. The file has contents, the stream is a handle that represents writing to the file.

Either flush `ofs` and read the file, or use `std::ostream &` in place of `std::ofstream &`.